# How can I access the object property inside subscribe to render the HTML?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I need to use the properties that I get inside `.subscribe` to update the HTML. I know that `.subscribe` is asynchronous so the value is undefined before it is resolved, but how can I make it wait until it has the value? At the moment I only get `undefined` for the object properties.

This is my service method where I call the API to fetch the data:

```
fetchCustomers(name: string) Observable<Customer[]> {

    return this.http.get<Customer>('MY URL')

}
```

and the component where I subscribe to it:

```
   customer: any;
   name: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.name = /*code to retrieve the name*/
    this.renderCustomer(this.name)
  }

  renderCustomer(name) {
      this.testService.fetchCustomer(name).subscribe(data => {
      this.customer = data
  })
}
```

But when I call the method `this.customer` remains undefined. I need the properties of `data` to render  my HTML file like this:

```html
 <tr> {{ customer.companyName }} </tr>
 <tr> {{ customer.fullName }} </tr>
 <tr> {{ customer.Email }} </tr>
```

How can I make this line `this.customer = data` to wait until the `Observable` is resolved? I have also tried `this.customer = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` as it was suggested in another thread, but it did not work.

Comment: That line **already** waits until the observable is resolved; that's the whole point of passing a callback. It's the first render of the template that doesn't. Either use safe navigation, conditionally render it with ngIf or expose an observable to the template and use the AsyncPipe.

Comment: thanks for the answers guys. I do not have access to the code at the moment. I'll try them once I got back to it

Comment: Why did you ask the question now, then?

Comment: because I could not do it at work

Comment: @Peyman Kheiri - **Salam Peyman** ,Customer is an interface or class  ?

Comment: sounds like you have two subscriptions and one is waiting on the other to get data.  Is this.name retrieved from a subscription as well? if so you can probably use rxjs flatMap to tie both the subscriptions together.

Comment: @AbolfazlR its an interface

Comment: @shahidfoy yes- this.name also is retireved from a subscription

Comment: @PeymanKheiri try using rxjs flatmap,  but the other answers will probably work as well.  you can make this.customer into an interface and give optional properties as well https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code looks right! Can you try using a safe navigation operator,

```
<tr> {{ customer?.companyName }} </tr>
<tr> {{ customer?.fullName }} </tr>
<tr> {{ customer?.Email }} </tr>
```

Comment: thanks. this worked. thanks for all of the answers guys! they were all great helps to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the safe navigation operator in the HTML:

```
 <tr> {{ customer?.companyName }} </tr>
 <tr> {{ customer?.fullName }} </tr>
 <tr> {{ customer?.Email }} </tr>
```

You can also display a loader until the data comes. Something like:

```
<ng-container ngIf="!customer"> 
  <spinner></spinner>
</ng-container>
<ng-container ngIf="customer"> 
   ...
   <tr> {{ customer.companyName }} </tr>
   <tr> {{ customer.fullName }} </tr>
   <tr> {{ customer.Email }} </tr>
   ...
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what @Sajeetharan suggests or wrap your `tr`'s into `if`:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="customer">
 <tr> {{ customer.companyName }} </tr>
 <tr> {{ customer.fullName }} </tr>
 <tr> {{ customer.Email }} </tr>
</ng-container>
```

This way it will be shown only if the `customer` has some value

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is only on the HTML itself, you can add a question mark to check if the object is defined first :

```html
 <tr> {{ customer?.companyName }} </tr>
```

Or you could simply use

`````
*ngIf="customer"
 ```` on the parent div.
`````

If you want to do other things inside your component you can open the callback to do more stuff.

**your_component.ts**

```
renderCustomer(name) {
      this.testService.fetchCustomer(name).subscribe(data => {
      this.customer = data;
      foo(data);
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `async` pipe

component

```
 customer$: Observable<any>;
 name: string;

 ngOnInit() {
   this.renderCustomer(this.name)
 }

 renderCustomer(name) {
   this.customer = this.testService.fetchCustomer(name)
 })
```

template

```
<tr> {{ customer.companyName | async }} </tr>
<tr> {{ customer.fullName | async  }} </tr>
<tr> {{ customer.Email | async  }} </tr>
```

Comment: I wouldn't do this.  1) I don't think that works 2)if it does, you will be making multiple async calls to your server.

Comment: You clearly have misunderstood how this works. 1) you should do this if you want cleaner code. 2) It doesn't make additional calls. Please check this nice tutorial. https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/pipes/async-pipe/#_summary

Comment: im pretty sure this line wont work ```{{ customer.companyName | async }}```

Answer (score 1):

If the customer model is an interface you can set default value null for each property like the following

```
public customer:Customer={ companyName: null, fullName: null, Email:null }
```

Then in your html :

```
<tr> {{ customer.companyName }} </tr>
<tr> {{ customer.fullName }} </tr>
<tr> {{ customer.Email }} </tr>
```

Another way is to use `?` operator as below :

```
<tr> {{ customer?.companyName }} </tr>
<tr> {{ customer?.fullName }} </tr>
<tr> {{ customer?.Email }} </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

If customer & name are both coming from subscriptions you might be able to chain them together using rxjs flatMap https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/flatMap

```
customer: any;
name: string;

ngOnInit() {
  this.renderCustomer();
}

renderCustomer() {
   this.testService.fetchName(/*variable to retrieve the name*/)
    .pipe(
      flatMap((name: string) => {
        this.name = name;
        return this.testService.fetchCustomer(name);
      })
    ).subscribe(data => {
       this.customer = data;
    });
}
```